# Display my Mapbox map in Openlayers 5.3.0?

Tags: mapbox, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5

I am trying to display my custom map from Mapbox in Openlayers 5.3.0. I am trying to follow the example [HERE](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/mapbox-with-openlayers/?fbclid=IwAR01r3D_89OVaz-YgEM2WjJxBusd7iUoXZF8jU9d2Dwn8slL9ZEqE86fRUA).

I am able to show the standard Mapbox background, but as soon as I change to my personal map style it breaks and shows a blank screen...

Here is example code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ZlbnB0IiwiYSI6ImNqc2Vxa3Q5MzBqcTAzeW1kOWRiajV4ZzYifQ.xpDqTM6B41sS6QjZPwb6yQ' //this works
        /*
        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/svenpt/cjsbq6vq716ye1fpgw10kvitp.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ZlbnB0IiwiYSI6ImNqc2Vxa3Q5MzBqcTAzeW1kOWRiajV4ZzYifQ.xpDqTM6B41sS6QjZPwb6yQ' //this doesn't work
        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/svenpt/cjsbq6vq716ye1fpgw10kvitp.html/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ZlbnB0IiwiYSI6ImNqc2Vxa3Q5MzBqcTAzeW1kOWRiajV4ZzYifQ.xpDqTM6B41sS6QjZPwb6yQ' //this doesn't work either
        */
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Comment: The last one looks correct except for the `.html` so try  `url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/svenpt/cjsbq6vq716ye1fpgw10kvitp/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ZlbnB0IiwiYSI6ImNqc2Vxa3Q5MzBqcTAzeW1kOWRiajV4ZzYifQ.xpDqTM6B41sS6QjZPwb6yQ'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to Mike for the answer!

The correct url is:

```
url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/svenpt/cjsbq6vq716ye1fpgw10kvitp/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ZlbnB0IiwiYSI6ImNqc2Vxa3Q5MzBqcTAzeW1kOWRiajV4ZzYifQ.xpDqTM6B41sS6QjZPwb6yQ'
```

I had to delte the `.html` from:

```
url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/svenpt/cjsbq6vq716ye1fpgw10kvitp.html/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ZlbnB0IiwiYSI6ImNqc2Vxa3Q5MzBqcTAzeW1kOWRiajV4ZzYifQ.xpDqTM6B41sS6QjZPwb6yQ'
```